# Front of the car(sedan) hitting speed bumps when approached at right angle

Tags: car, bumper, weight

The front end of my sedan hits on bumps if I approach at a right angle. The mid/rear portion of the car doesn't hit bumps and mid/rear clearance is decent however the front clearance is poor. My doubt here is that does the  number of people sitting(weight) in the back seats affect the probability of the front hitting the bump, the weight in the 2 front seats remains constant. If yes, then does more weight at back increase or reduce the probability ?

Comment: Please provide more details about this problem. What is the make/model of your car? Since when is this happening, can we correlate it with an event?

Comment: Hyundai Verna (/Hyundai Accent). Its been happening ever since it was bought. 
 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyundai_Accent

Comment: ps: Its a used model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any additional weight in the passenger compartment will be spread across all four wheels, but obviously not equally. If the additional weight is nearer the rear wheels, they will receive more of the weight, but some will be on the front. So extra passengers would make it more likely for you to ground the front of the car.

To lift the front of the car you would have to add weight behind the rear wheels.  This video illustrates this - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=U7zb7qnZBvs
The trunk (boot) of the vehicle was loaded with a heavy weight which balanced the vehicle on the rear axle.